Stratified sampling across several variables individually
I am interested stratified sampling for the purposes of cluster validation. The purpose is to perform cluster analysis in a subset of the data and check to see if the precise distribution of variables that occurs in that cluster analysis is consistent with the subset that wasn't actually involved in the original clustering.
Say I am stratifying over height (tall or short) and age (old or young). It's my understanding that in traditional supervised learning contexts, a common stratified sampling approach may be to create strata by the combinations of these variables (tall-old, tall-young, short-old, short-young) and then to sample from these strata appropriately.
I'd like to split my observations into two groups, A and B, such that A and B have approximately equal proportions of young vs. old and approximately equal proportions of short vs. tall. But I do not want to necessarily force these two groups to have approximately equal proportions of tall-old, tall-young, short-old, short-young.
Currently, the way I'm planning on achieving this is simply by randomly partitioning my observations a huge number of times, calculating the sum of squared errors in the A vs. B proportions of tall/short and young/old, and then picking whichever random partition had the lowest such error at the end of the day.
My questions are:

Is there something explicitly nonsensical of what I am trying to do?
Is there a better way to do this sort of sampling? I am doing this in R but welcome general recommendations too.
Does this kind of sampling have a name?


How big is your overall dataset?

@jbowman About 400 observations and 60 features.
